# Apple Mail fails to interpret

Tags: mail.app, encoding

I use Apple Mail Version 4.6 (1085) under OS 10.6.8. From time to time I find this kind of thing in my Inbox:

--_004_366988BF4C7E3E47BD2D208797A90F7E01662044FD892008SERVERL_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_366988BF4C7E3E47BD2D208797A90F7E01662044FD892008SERVERL_"

--_000_366988BF4C7E3E47BD2D208797A90F7E01662044FD892008SERVERL_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

W2NpZDppbWFnZTAwMS5qcGdAMDFDRUFCMEMuQ0U1Mjk5NDBdDQoNCkRlYXIgUHJvZmVzc29yIEVw
c3RlaW4NCg0KV2VsY29tZSB0byB5b3VyIGxhdGVzdCBMTVMgZS1VcGRhdGU6IDYgU2VwdGVtYmVy

All my mail goes through my university and is forwarded to Apple Mail. I don't think anything is changed by the forwarding process, though I'm not 100% sure about this. When I look at the same message using the university's webmail system, the message has been correctly interpreted and I can just read it without further ado.

Have I got some setting wrong on my Apple Mail preferences, or is Apple Mail unable to deal dorrectly with messages of this kind. I suppose that the message may not adhere totally strictly to the correct protocol.

Any help to get my Apple Mail working as I would like would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know is it a IMAP or POP type. Do you know if you use SSL. Those things you can look up in Mail preferences.

Comment: It's IMAP and uses SSL. I should stress that it's only occasionally that Apple Mail does not interpret correctly. Is there a way of looking at the source of a message? I might be able to see how the failing messages are different---not that that would necessarily help.

Answer (score 1):

For sporadic email formatting errors:

To look at the original message (email) before format changes

select the email

then click on the View and Message

then select RAW format.

it will show you all details of that file.